# Class Not found when try to acces the class in the library of a android module from another Android module

Tags: android-studio-import

I have a Android library module (Common), which has a library dependency (com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1). Alongside "Common" module I have an Android module (Module1)ich requires "MultiDex" (located as dependency within the "Common" Library Module), but I get an error: android.support.multidex.MultiDex does not exist.

Common Library build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Module1  build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':Common');
}
```

But in Module1 i am unable to use MultiDex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your build.gradle you need to enable multidex as:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true


   }
    ...
}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Hope this helps..